# Nullpointer Exception unknown resource springmicriservice

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

> cnv any one help me I dont knoe where make mistake,when i run my
> application in chrome in browser when type
> http://localhost:8100/currency-converter-feign/from/USD/to/INR/quantity/1000
> i got this type of erro
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
> this as a fallback.
>
> Fri Jul 17 21:38:29 IST 2020 There was an unexpected error
> (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). No message available
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> java.math.BigDecimal.multiply(Unknown Source) at
> com.main.conteoller.CurrencyconversionController.convertCurencyFfeign(CurrencyconversionController.java:47)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:142)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at
>
> currencyconvertercontroller.java

```
package com.main.conteoller;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.main.Bean.ConversionBean;
import com.main.serviceproxy.CurrencyexchangeserviceProxy;

@RestController
public class CurrencyconversionController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CurrencyexchangeserviceProxy proxy;
    
    @GetMapping("/currency-converter/from/{from}/to/{to}/quantity/{quantity}")
    public ConversionBean convertCurency(@PathVariable String from,
            @PathVariable String to,
            @PathVariable BigDecimal quantity) {
        
        Map<String, String>uriVariables= new HashMap<>(); 
        uriVariables.put("from", from);
        uriVariables.put("to", to);
        ResponseEntity<ConversionBean>resp = new RestTemplate()
                .getForEntity("http://localhost:8000/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}",
                ConversionBean.class,
                uriVariables);
               ConversionBean cbresp=resp.getBody();
        return new ConversionBean(cbresp.getId(),from,to,cbresp.getConvermultiple(),
                        quantity,quantity.multiply(cbresp.getConvermultiple()),cbresp.getPort());
        
    }
    @GetMapping("/currency-converter-feign/from/{from}/to/{to}/quantity/{quantity}")
    public ConversionBean convertCurencyFfeign(@PathVariable String from,
            @PathVariable String to,
            @PathVariable BigDecimal quantity) {
        
               ConversionBean cbresp=proxy.retrivefromexchange(from, to);
        return new ConversionBean(cbresp.getId(),from,to,cbresp.getConvermultiple(),
                        quantity,quantity.multiply(cbresp.getConvermultiple()),cbresp.getPort());
        
    }
}
```

> currencybean.java

```
package com.main.Bean;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class ConversionBean {
    private int id;
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private BigDecimal convermultiple;
    private BigDecimal quantity;
    private BigDecimal totalCalamount;
    private int port;
    
    public ConversionBean() {}
    
    public ConversionBean(int id, String from, String to, BigDecimal convermultiple, BigDecimal quantity,
            BigDecimal totalCalamount, int port) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.convermultiple = convermultiple;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.totalCalamount = totalCalamount;
        this.port = port;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }
    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }
    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }
    public BigDecimal getConvermultiple() {
        return convermultiple;
    }
    public void setConvermultiple(BigDecimal convermultiple) {
        this.convermultiple = convermultiple;
    }
    public BigDecimal getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(BigDecimal quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public BigDecimal getTotalCalamount() {
        return totalCalamount;
    }
    public void setTotalCalamount(BigDecimal totalCalamount) {
        this.totalCalamount = totalCalamount;
    }
    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    

}
```

> currencyexchangeproxy.java

```
package com.main.serviceproxy;

import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;


import com.main.Bean.ConversionBean;

@FeignClient(name="currency-exchange",url="localhost:8000")

public interface CurrencyexchangeserviceProxy {
    @GetMapping("/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}")
    public ConversionBean retrivefromexchange(@PathVariable ("from") String from,
            @PathVariable ("to") String to);

}
```

Comment: Do you have the @EnableFeignClients somewhere in your project? If not please put it to your application class and try again.

Comment: @EnableFeignClients it is declared in my main method below my SpringBootApplication

Answer (score 2):

> It is occurs due to mismatch of comumn name in your  db table and in
> your entity class. Because I use micriservices,I call some exchange
> rates from another project by provideing its url in my repository, in
> that project i privide same name in my entity class and in my db table
> ,but i declared diffrent name in my exchange service project. there i
> declare **conversationmultople** and here declare **convermultiple**
> .make sure both name same in db and your bean class

Answer (score 2):

> @EnableFeignClient service in your springboot main method
>
> for example

package com.main;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients("com.main.serviceproxy")
public class CurrencyConversionServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CurrencyConversionServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```